# Show all entries except most recent

Tags: channel-entries

I have a new page that I am pulling the most recent entry to feature on the page. I need to list out the rest of the entries except for the most recent entry.

How can I use the channel entries tag to show all entries except for the most recent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [offset](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#offset) parameter.  Like:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="10" offset="1" orderby="date"}
```